# Computing the associated graded ring and its Poincaré/Hilbert series

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, graded-rings

Suppose $R=k[x,y]/(f)$, where $k$ a field, $f=y^d+g\in k[x,y]$ and $g\in(x,y)^{d+1}$ with $d$ a fixed positive integer. The ideal $I=(x,y)$ is maximal in $R$.

The associated graded ring $A=G_I(R)$ should be $\bigoplus_{n=0}^{\infty}(x,y)^n/(x,y)^{n+1}$ by definition, viewed as an A-module. The ring $A$ is graded because $I^n/I^{n+1}\cdot I^m/I^{m+1}=I^{n+m}/I^{n+m+1}$.

If we let $\lambda=\dim_k$, how can we compute the Poincaré/Hilbert series $P_{\lambda}(A,t)=\Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty}\lambda(A_n)t^n$?

For every $A_n$ (which I think is equal to $I^n/I^{n+1}$) we need to compute the dimension over $k$ ($\dim=2$?). I think these dimensions should depend on $d$, but I don't see how to continue.

I'm absolutely clueless. Does anyone have a good hint to help me further? I think I'm overthinking this completely.

EDIT:
I thought of something. We know that $g\in A_{d+1}$, the set of polynomials in $A$ of degree $d+1$. So $f\in A_d \cup A_{d+1}$. It's so hard to see for me how to get the Poincaré/Hilbert series of the associated graded ring in stead of just for $R$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez For $n=0$ we have $A_0=R/(x,y)=k$, for $n=1$ we have $A_1=(x,y)/(x,y)^2=I\cdot k$, so $G_I(R)=k\oplus Ik\oplus I^2k\oplus ...$. Each dimension is then 2 because each step the basis gets two new elements, the $x^n$ and $y^n$. But when does the polynomial $f$ factor in here?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Do you mean $I^n/I^{n+1}$?

Comment: $x^3y^2$ is zero modulo $I^n$ for $n\geqslant 2$

Comment: Oh, I mean zero for $n\leqslant3$

Comment: Hmm, but then $x^3y^2$ is in $(x,y),(x,y)^2$ and $(x,y)^3$. However $x^3$ is not in $I^4$, so then the basis for $I^4/I^5$ is really the basis for $I^3/I^4$ with $x^4$ and $y^4$ included right?